# Notification hub device registration with installation

Tags: xamarin.forms, azure-notificationhub

After reading [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/notification-hubs/notification-hubs-push-notification-registration-management) I've been trying to create an installation in my xamarin.android app but I keep getting an 'Unauthorized error'    I feel that I'm missing something.  Any help is appreciated.

Previously I was able to register with the hub using 
`var regID = hub.Register(token, tags.ToArray()).RegistrationId;` 
so I'm sure my hub has been setup correctly and that I am using the correct connectionstring.

My installation object

```
install.installationId = installationId; //guid
install.tags = Tags;
install.platform = "gcm";
install.pushChannel = token; //refresh token from fcm
```

Call to Create installation

```
private async Task<HttpStatusCode> CreateOrUpdateInstallationAsync(DeviceInstallation deviceInstallation,
        string hubName, string listenConnectionString)
        {
            if (deviceInstallation.installationId == null)
                return HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;

            // Parse connection string (https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/dn495627.aspx)
            ConnectionStringUtility connectionSaSUtil = new ConnectionStringUtility(listenConnectionString);
            string hubResource = "installations/" + deviceInstallation.installationId + "?";
            string apiVersion = "api-version=2015-04";

            // Determine the targetUri that we will sign
            string uri = connectionSaSUtil.Endpoint + hubName + "/" + hubResource + apiVersion;

            //=== Generate SaS Security Token for Authorization header ===
            // See, https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/dn495627.aspx
            string SasToken = connectionSaSUtil.getSaSToken(uri, 60);

            using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
            {
                string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(deviceInstallation);

                httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", SasToken);

                var response = await httpClient.PutAsync(uri, new StringContent(json, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));
                return response.StatusCode;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Please make sure url parameter that if is correct, when you create the MobileServiceClient object in the PCL.The correct url type is ""http://yourmobileappname.azurewebsites.net" like this link.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44395331/unauthorized-exception-when-trying-to-register-xamarin-app-with-azure-notificati

Comment: This code is located in my Xamarin.Android project and I am only using the notification hub for notifications.  The uri is coming from the listenconnectionstring and broken apart using code from [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/dn495627.aspx).  The example I cited above was written for UWP(I think) and in that they do not reference any MobileServceClient objects.

Comment: The code I used to create the token was not correct.  I used the code from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/eventhub/generate-sas-token) instead.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your sharing.